Two-Dimensional Array Subscripting (Stack-Based vs Heap-Based)
When I compile this program:
/* Create a 3 x 3 2D integer array */
int* matrix = calloc(3 * 3, sizeof(int));
/* This will cause an error since we
 * can't use double subscript on a
 * single pointer */
matrix[0][0] = 1;

I get the following error:
$ gcc main.c -o main -Wall
main.c: In function ‘main':
main.c:10:14: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
   10 |     matrix[0][0] = 1;
      |              ^

To me, this makes sense, as to my understanding, subscript operators ([]) are only valid for arrays and pointers. Because a one-dimensional array is simply a list of integers, using a subscript operator on it twice, like [0][0] fails due to the fact that the first subscript operation returns an integer value, not a pointer or array that could accept a second subscript operator.
However to me, this contradicts how arrays are allocated "statically", like so:
int matrix[3][3] = {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 7, 8, 9 }
};

How come with an array that has been declared and initialized this way, I can use [0][0], even though this array is essentially a one-dimensional array being implemented with fancy offsetting techniques like so:
matrix[Row Index][Column Index] = Base Address + ((Row Index * Number of Columns) + Column Index) * sizeof(Element)

Why can I not use the same with an array declared dynamically using calloc like the first example? What is it I'm not understanding?


How come with an array that has been declared and initialized this
way, I can use [0][0], even though this array is essentially a
one-dimensional array being implemented with fancy offsetting
techniques like so:

There is the C grammar and its semantic according to which there can be defined arrays of different dimensions and be accessed with different number of the subscript operator.
This expression
matrix[Row Index][Column Index]

uses the pointer arihmetic and is evaluated the following way. The array designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element (that has the type int[3]) of the type int ( * )[3]. Then with the pointer arithmetic a pointer to the required row Row Index is evaluted like ( p + Row Index ) where p is the pointer to the first element of the array as it is pointed to above. After that the pointer is dereferenced to get the required row of the type int[3]: *( p + Row Index ). The obtained one dimensional array again is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type int * and using the same pointer arithmetic you get a pointer to the required element: ( *( p + Row Index ) + Column Index ). And at last to get the element itself you need to dereference the resulted pointer *( *( p + Row Index ) + Column Index ). That is after applying the first subscript operator you need to obtain a pointer to apply the second subscript operator.
As for using calloc then if you want to allocate indeed a two-dimensional array then you can write
int ( *matrix )[3] = calloc(3 * 3, sizeof(int));



How come with an array that has been declared and initialized this way, I can use [0][0] even though this array is essentially a one-dimensional array ...

No, it's not a one-dimentional array. It's an array of arrays of int.
I think the confusion comes from the implicit conversion that (with a few exceptions, e.g. sizeof) happens when using an array in C:
When using an array there is an implicit conversion to a pointer to the first element of the array.
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

foo(arr);
    ^^^
    The passed argument is not the array {1, 2, 3}. The implicit
    conversion rule means that the passed argument is a pointer
    to the first element. As the first element is an int, the passed
    pointer will have the type int* (pointer to int).

    foo(arr) is the same as foo(&arr[0]).

Just the same happens for the 2D array which is really an array of array of int.
With
int matrix[3][3] = {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 7, 8, 9 }
};

matrix[1] is an array of int (here it's { 4, 5, 6 }). But due to the implicit conversion rule for arrays, matrix[1] will (with a few exceptions) be converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.
So matrix[1] will be the same as &matrix[1][0], and the type will be int* (pointer to int).
Consequently, matrix[1][0] is the same as *(&matrix[1][0]) or just *&matrix[1][0]). That's why you can access your "2D array" using [i][j] syntax.
For dynamic allocation of a 2D array of int (array of array of int), you'll need a variable of type "pointer to array of int". It looks like:
int (*p)[3];  // p is a pointer to an array of 3 int

and allocation is done like
p = malloc(42 * sizeof(*p));

now p can be used just as if it had been defined like int p[42][3].
Notice the sizeof(*p) part. Due to the *, it means "size of what p points to". As p points to an array of 3 int, it's the same as "size of array of 3 int". This is one of the few exceptions where the implicit conversion to a pointer doesn't take place.
BTW:
In general when doing dynamic allocation it's a good idea to use the syntax:
TYPE *X = malloc( N * sizeof(*X));
                      ^^^^^^^^^^

where N is the number of elements of type TYPE, you need.
